# How to UNPIVOT a table without a UNPIVOT operator?

Tags: sql

Given this example:
[Pivoted Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlR6L.png)

And the desired output is the following:
[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TJCc.png)

So my question is. I'm running a proprietary server which I cannot mention here and this server does not support UNPIVOT operator. I have tried so far the following:

```
SELECT week,
       day,
       username,
       CASE
           WHEN main_cat_1 = "cars" THEN "cars"
           WHEN main_cat_2 = "vans" THEN "vans"
       ELSE null END AS main_cat,
       CASE
           WHEN sub_cat_1.1 = "dirty" THEN "dirty"
           WHEN sub_cat_1.2 = "stalled" THEN "stalled"
       ELSE null END AS sub_cat
       FROM table1
```

The issue with this approach is that because of **short-circuit evaluation** after the first TRUE valueit does not seem to work properly and does not return the expected values.

Comment: Your query is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT week,
    day,
    username,
    main_cat_1 as category,
    sub_cat_1.1 as subcategory
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT week,
    day,
    username,
    main_cat_1,
    sub_cat_1.2
FROM table1
UNION
...etc.
```